# Hive Order by Not working

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

**Query:**

**Column without function:**

SELECT **ACCOUNTID** from table **order by** ACCOUNTID;

(Above query works fine in both HIVE & MYSQL)

**Column with function:**

SELECT **concat('test_',ACCOUNTID)** from table **order by** ACCOUNTID;

In mysql , Above query  working fine.

In hive, below exception thrown

**FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: 
Line 1:59 Invalid table alias or column reference 'ACCOUNTID': 
(possible column names are: _c0)**

Mysql :

**Order by** working fine with columns involved in functions

Hive :

**Order by** is **not** working with columns involved in functions

Temporary Solution :

SELECT **concat('test_',ACCOUNTID) as tempColumn** from table **order by** tempcolumn;

Is there any solution available without assigning column as tempcolumn ?

Note:

**i want concatenated result alone(test_ACCOUNTID).. without exposing ACCOUNTID as another column**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can also select the accountid column for sorting.

```
SELECT accountid,concat('test_',ACCOUNTID) from table order by accountid;
```

Or, rename "concat('test_', accountid) " as accountid, like this:

```
SELECT concat('test_',ACCOUNTID) accountid from table order by accountid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you want your concatenated results to appear in the order of *account id* then you can expose ACCOUNTID in the projection list

```
SELECT concat('test_',ACCOUNTID), ACCOUNTID FROM <table> ORDER BY ACCOUNTID
```

Comment: i want concatenated result alone(test_ACCOUNTID).. without exposing ACCOUNTID as another column.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge,its the only way to use alias-name for function expression and use clauses like 'Group By','Order By','Sort By' using that alias-name.